# using System::Drawing namespace in managed C++ class library

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, managed

I am moving a few functions from a Managed C++ Winforms app to a class library so that I can call them in a new C# app I'm writing. However one of the functions returns a System::Drawing::Bitmap^ and uses the System::Drawing::Color class which is causing an error saying that System does not contain a namespace called Drawing ...

Obviously it does, but I'm guessing that since a class library does not intrinsically have a graphical element to it like a winform does that there may be an extra step for accessing the functionality?

What do i need to add/link-to?

Thank you in advance.

Tony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add a reference to `System.Drawing.dll`. Right-click your project and choose "Add Reference", it should be there somewhere.

Comment: Check if the library folders are in the path where the compiler searches for. Options->Project&sols->VC++Directories.